# Cmd errors out when using pip

Tags: python, pip

Python is installed. Idlie works. Cmd is able to find the python app but is unable to find pip. Followed the installer and selected pip installation. Errors in command prompt:traceback (most recent call last):
, line 1, in 
Nameerror: name 'pip's is not defined.
What to do?!?!

Comment: `pip` should be used from command line (i.e. CMD), not from python interactive shell (i.e. that is when you have `>>>`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Nameerror%3A+name+pip+is+not+defined

Comment: I used it in cmd. However the location doesnt actually have pip. I think that's my issue. I dont see a script folder. I should have to had my own script folder and add pip? It should be automatic in the installer? I have tried the method below and still says name pip is not defines

Answer (score 1):

Pip is more user friendly when used from cmd {Assuming you are on windows and have python installed}

1. Click on windows icon
2. Type `cmd` This would bring up the command prompt page
3. Browse through to where your `python.exe` is installed. You should also be seeing a folder called "Scripts". Open it.
4. Copy the folder path. It should be something like `C:....\Python\Scripts\`
5. Go back to the command prompt window.
6. Type `cd C:....\Python\Scripts\` and press enter. This should change your current directory to the place where `pip` is.
7. To check your version of pip; type `pip --version` and press enter.
8. To install different modules via pip, type `pip install (whatever without the brackets)`

Follow this link https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/3